# Laravel : How to invalidate all sessions of a user from redis and logged out from all devices?

Tags: laravel, session, redis

An Application using Redis based sessions with Laravel 5.2.

Need to logout user from all devices, for that, using Session::getId() to fetch session id and store into the database against user id. The approach is to destroy all user specific sessions from Redis DB accept current logged-in sessions by storing all user maintained sessions into the database.

When I get session id of a user from Redis-CLI KEY '[value]', the value of the key not matched the id which is fetched by using `Session::getId()`. For this, couldn't be able to logout user from all devices.

I need to destroy users all sessions from Redis so all logged-in devices will be logged out.

Please help me out how can I destroy user all session from Redis database because `Session::getId()` value and Redis-CLI Key [value] doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel ships with a function that logs the user out on every device except the one he uses currently:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password);
```

[See more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its available for only 5.7 version of laravel and I'm using 5.2

Comment: I'd suggest updating

Comment: updating version is very risky for the running product which is under use by thousand of users. Can you suggest me another one?